# Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, ruby-on-rails-4

I have come across this deprecation warning when adding search functionality to an app I'm building. I'm using rails 4.

Here's my entire search controller.

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @links = Link.search(title: params[:q]).page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
  end
end
```

I'm fairly new to rails, but I have a feeling this has to do with strong parameters. Any suggestions on how I could get past this warning?

I'm using Textacular: https://github.com/textacular/textacular

Comment: What search engine do you use?

Comment: Can you share the implementation of the "search" method? That's likely where the call to Model.scoped resides.

Comment: Gah! Sorry, I left this out. I'm using textacular.

Comment: Where does this warning exactly point?

Comment: called from index at /app/controllers/search_controller.rb:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/textacular/textacular/commit/af3d1d2b64966b641983e5c6a3e450aae6d0a987

So it probably comes from `Textacular` gem.

Comment: but isn't that commit supposed to solve the issue? I'm still getting it.

Comment: @DavidBecerra Textacular version on rubygems probably doesn't have this commit yet.

Comment: That is exactly right. I installed the gem from github directly and it works nicely now without the warning. Thanks for your help.